# How to assign spring kafka container to particular partitions and be able to stop/start it?

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need container that I can start/stop. Also in my program I need to assign to particular partitions. But I can't understand how to achive both conditions.

**In the first case** I can do something like that (Excuse My Kotlin):

```
val consumerProps = props.consumer.buildProperties()

val containerProps = ContainerProperties(topic)
containerProps.pollTimeout = 1_000

val enableAutoCommit = consumerProps[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG]?.let { it as Boolean }
if (enableAutoCommit == null || !enableAutoCommit) {
    containerProps.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
}

val container = ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(factory, containerProps)
container.setupMessageListener(listener)
container.concurrency = CONCURRENCY
```

I can't see any option to add partions information in this snippet.

**In the second case** I can do something like that:

```
    // @Autowired private val listenerContainerFactory: ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    val container =  listenerContainerFactory.createContainer(
            partitions.map { TopicPartitionInitialOffset(topic, it.partition()) }
    )
```

And I can't see any option to change `ackMode` at this configuration.

Comment: Consumers are meant to run indefinitely. Can you describe your use case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference to the container configuration regardless of the topic configuration (topics, pattern, topic/partitions).

You can use

```
val container = ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(factory, containerProps)
```

with a `containerProps` created with a `TopicPartitionInitialOffset` (you don't have to use the factory).

If you need to use the factory for some reason, you can use

```
container.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

after the container is created.